# How to use jquery selector to get the following text?

Tags: jquery

Suppose the website's html looks like this.

```
<img src="pic/helloworld_123.jpg" width="48" border="0" alt="" title="">
```

How to use jquery selector to get the following text?

```
helloworld_123.jpg
```

Thx

I tested this but it doesn't work.

```
$("img[src*='']").text();
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the URL of the image?

Comment: *"no only the text"* images don't have "text".

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("img").attr("src").split("/").pop(); // it will get the src of image, split it using "/" and get the last index of an array which is "helloworld_123.jpg"
```

```js
console.log($("img").attr("src").split("/").pop());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="pic/helloworld_123.jpg" width="48" border="0" alt="" title="">
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right:

```
$("img").attr('src');
```

Then you can parse src attribute as you want

```
$("img").attr('src').split('/').pop()
```

For multiple images use

```
$("img").each(function(){ $("img").attr('src'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var src = $('img').attr('src');
  var name = src.split('/');
  alert(name[1]);          
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="pic/helloworld_123.jpg" width="48" border="0" alt="" title="">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('img').attr('src').substring($('img').attr('src').indexOf('/') +1)
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Yep, feeling some lazy sorry